# My salary from Dubai to India in INR ; taxable or not

Tags: india, bank-account, non-resident, salary, inr-indian-rupee

I am working in dubai since 3rd may 2013 to till date and receiving my salary in INR in India in ICICI Saving account. I have not filled my ITR.
I wish to know :

1. Can I fill my ITR now and what is the time line.
2. Is my salary tax free because as per my employer this salary transfers in India as tax free. If it is free then in which category I will have to mention so as my individual form of ITR can pick my salary base as tax free.

Is there any helpline in India who can guide me about this issue.

As I have to take home loan in India for which bank have been asking for ITR of last 3 years. Kindly help me in this regard

Answer (score 2):

> receiving my salary in INR in India in ICICI Saving account

As an NRI you cannot have Savings account. Please have this converted to NRO ASAP and open an NRE account.

> Can I fill my ITR now and what is the time line.

Generally if taxes are due, returns need to be filed by July 31 same year. If no taxes due, then 31 Mar next year.

So for the financial year 1 April 13 to 31 March 14, the date was 31 July 14 or 31 March 15. You have missed both. You can still file returns with category as after due date.

For the financial year 1 Apr 14 to 31 March 15, this year you can file upto 31 Aug 15 or 31 Mar 16. You still have time for both.

If you are an NRI, salary certificate from your employer would also help. ITR's are not must.